# UTF-8 Character in CSS

Tags: css, utf-8

I have been using an html template that contains a slider (revolution slider - https://revolution.themepunch.com/)

It has a right and left arrow for navigating that use the following -

```
.tp-rightarrow.preview4:after { content: '\E824'; }
.tp-leftarrow.preview4:after { content: '\E825'; }
```

This works fine locally, but when I uploaded as part of an Umbraco site the two arrows changed to Chinese symbols. When I googled I found the following -

http://www.utf8icons.com/character/59429/UTF-8-character

I have now changed the CSS to display a > and < symbol but I'd like to know why the original code sometimes displays arrows and sometime displays chinese symbols.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your HTML document have a charset meta? It can also be set through a PHP header. You may include the charset in the CSS file itself using `@charset "UTF-8";`

Comment: @Aziz Since that CSS notation uses pure ASCII characters, encodings don't play any role here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

U+E824 and ..25 are code points in the *private use area*. Code points in that area are *not reserved*, they do not have any pre-defined meaning. They are neither defined as Chinese characters nor arrows. You are free to use any private use code point for any purpose you wish, **as long as the publisher and the client are in agreement what these code points mean.**

In the browser this pretty much just boils down to having the right fonts installed/loaded/defined. In a web page, each character is simply rendered by the first defined/responsible font which happens to contain a glyph for that code point. The reason why it renders differently on two different systems/environments therefore can only stem from the fact that the CSS font definitions differ, or that the browser has different fonts installed.

Most likely the original included a custom web font which defined these characters as arrows. You have either omitted that font, or you have overridden the font precedence and made a different font apply to that element, and that font happens to define Chinese characters at those code points.